# Node, Express - Templating engine not displaying views

Tags: node.js, express

In my project, I use the ejs templating engine in order to display HTML to the user. I use the `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` command in my index file to tell express which templating engine I am using.

In a separate file, I then use the `router` object to handle a get request. Within that request, I use the line `return res.render('landing')` to return my template. This template is stored in a folder named **views** which is in my root directory (default location).

When I make a request, I get returned the message `Cannot GET /` in the browser.

Here is my code:
**index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

require('./startup/logging') ()
require('./startup/db') ()
require('./startup/routes') (app)
require('./startup/server') (app)
```

**landing.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('landing')
})
```

Does anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you requiring `landing.js`?

Comment: Also, it looks like your router isn't connected to the app? `app.use('/', router)` or so

Comment: @niry I don't require **landing.js** anywhere.

Comment: @niry Sorry I am new to express. Do I need to require it? What else do I need to do in order to use it?

Comment: your problem solved ?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar No it has not solved it.

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I add `require('./routes/landing') ` in my index file, but I still get returned the same error.

Comment: @niry After adding `require('./routes/landing') ` in my index file, the templating engine still does not display in the browser like before.

Comment: please write code at landing.js 
 const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('landing')
})

module.exports = router;

Comment: run above code ?